# Why no Holy Roman Emperor ever accepted a name, coinciding with a name of a Roman Emperor?

Tags: roman-empire, names, holy-roman-empire

For instance, no Holy Roman Emperor was named Constantine, or Alexander etc. On the other hand, many Byzantine emperors had names of previous Roman emperors (Constantine, Theodosios, Tiberios, Justinian, Anastasios, etc).

There are some Holy Roman Emperors with Latin-derived names, such as Maximilian, but the Roman emperors had different names, even if similar, such as Maximinus, Maximus, Maximianus.

Many Latin names are or were popular in Germany, such as Marcus, Martin, Justin and Julius. But it seems the Emperors avoided them. Some Holy Roman Emperors had name Otto, which is similar to Otho, but still different.

At the same time, many Popes took names, coinciding with those of Roman Emperors.

For comparison, just a list of grand princes of Rus that had names, coinciding with names of Roman or Byzantine emperors (up to spelling and adaptation): Konstantin, Mikhail, Alexander, Vasily, Ioann, Feodor, Alexis, Peter. Some of them repeat many times.

Comment: A *regnal name* is the personal choice of the monarch, made upon coronation. The reason for any choice (and non-choice) will be different for every single monarch, and of the deepest possible personal meaning. Unless explicitly cited by the monarch - ***no-one will ever know the reasons***. The question is unanswerable because of the intense personal nature of each choice made.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens For instance, kings of Poland had names Augustus, John, Alexander, kings of Russia were named Alexios, Ioannes, Petrus - all coinciding with names of Roman or Byzantine emperors.

Comment: If you desired to know why a particular Emperor chose a particular name, that ***might*** be an answerable question. Asking why a sesquimillennial succession of emperors failed to make a particular choice, or style of  choices, is simply unanswerable.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens since this is highly improbable, there should be some rule acting.

Comment: I think the question points to the difference between dynasties (as basis for monarchial systems) / dynastic monarchies on the one hand and elective systems / monarchies on the other. If an emperor wants to stress his dynastic roots and family tradition, he may choose a "familiar" name. In contrary, a pope, even being a Borgia or a Borghese, may choose a different "reference" (see WP on [Papal Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_name)).

Comment: @tohuwawohu Polish kings, Russian princess often used names, coinciding with Roman emperors. Holy Roman Emperors, not a single time.

Comment: @tohuwawohu even among English monarchs you can see a John and a Philip (the later is son of a Holy Roman Emperor, by the way, so this is not a family tradition.

Comment: I think this is a [consensus of historians #3](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4271/1401) anti-pattern

Comment: Did the Holy Roman Emperors pick regnal names?  My impression is that most used their birth name, so the naming is more about naming conventions in their birth culture.

Comment: There is little commonality of names between the Western Roman empire and the Byzantine empire either.   You can't expect rigorous rules in tradition.

Comment: @GorttheRobot then why some offsprings of holy Roman Emperors had names, coinciding with Roman Emperors? Examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_I_of_Castile https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_II_of_Spain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_of_Austria

Comment: @GorttheRobot yes. And this looks like intentional. There is no HRE emperor John, etc.

Comment: "looks intentional"?   Do you have any historical evidence that it *was* intentional?  I mean, @MarkC.Wallace has a name shared by many important Romans, but I suspect that has nothing to do with why he has it.

Comment: Shame. I kind of like this question, and I don't think we are entirely as recordless on this matter as some of the comments are implying.

Comment: @Anixx  The big logical flaw in your question is that if the Holy Roman Emperors were Roman Emperors, their names were names of Roman Emperors.  And I might ask how many eastern Roman or "Byzantine" emperors after the year 800 used the same names as earlier emperors - only 2 Leos and 5 Constantines.  Though many classical Roman emperors used throne names, the "Byzantine" and Holy Roman Emperors used the names they were given by their parents.

Comment: @Anixx Haven't you ever heard of Philip, King of the Romans and always emperor, who used the name of a couple of classical emperors, and in fact called himself Philip II:   
Philippus secundus divina favente clementia Romanorum rex et semper augustus  http://www.eurulers.altervista.org/emperors.html

Comment: @MAGolding a lot of Byzantine emperors used the names from pre-Byzantine times. I mentioned in the question Constantine, Theodosius, Tiberius, Justinian, Anastasios. There were also Alexander, Marcus.

Comment: @MAGolding Philippus was not a Holy Roman Emperor, that's the thing. A lot of European monarchs had name Philippus, including children of the Holy Roman Emperors, not a single emperor.

Comment: @Anixx  And none of those names was used by any "Byzantine" emperor reiging after the coronation of Charlemagne in 800, except for Leo and Constantine, and 1 Alexander.  The later "Byzantine" and the Holy Roman Emperors mostly used Christian names and pagan names which became Christian when used by saints.

Comment: @MAGolding there were also many Johns, the first being in 423-425, the last one in 1392.

Comment: @MAGolding Also do not forget Flavius, such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantine_VII and Phocas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikephoros_II_Phokas

Comment: @Anixx.  Philip was a Holy Roman Emperor. The title of classical era Roman Emperors was Imperator Caesar Augustus. The Early Holy Roman Emperors used the title of imperator Augustus.  Before 1200 the practice became that a man elected emperor, as Philip was elected, took the title of Rex Romanorum et semper Augustus, and after coronation in Rome took the title of Imperator Romanorum et semper Augustus.  The semper Augustus in the titles shows that they were alwasy emperor, that the King of the Romans had all the rights and powers of the Emperor of the Romans.

Comment: @MAGolding Philipp II was never a Holy Roman Emperor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Roman_Emperor

Comment: @Anixx Johannes 423-425 can be considerd either a Roman Emperor or a Roman usurper.  No "Byzantine" Emperor used the John until the 960s, andmodern historians number hm as john I.

Comment: @MAGolding "semper" (permanent) Augustus shows it is title, not a name (the word "Augustus" means "elevated" or "venerated" in Latin).

Comment: @Anixx that is my point, that Augustus is part of the imperial title, and part of the title of the King of the Romans.

Comment: @MAGolding the word "semper" possibly added so to underline it was not a name.

Comment: @Flavius Phocas (r. 602-607) doesn't seem to have a recorded personal name, Flavius and Phocas being family names - or else Flavius was part of the imperial title.  There is no known connection between him and the later Byzantien noble family of Phocas that Nikephoros II belonged to, and in any case Byzantine surnames wer handed down from generation to generation and not chosen by a man or by his parents.

Comment: I note that Emperor Frederick II was apaprently named Constantine at birth and wasn''t named Frederick Roger until he was baptised 2 year later.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_II,_Holy_Roman_Emperor#Birth_and_naming   https://fmg.ac/Projects/MedLands/GERMANY,%20Kings.htm#FriedrichIIGermanydied1250A

Comment: @MAGolding so even having the birth name Constantine, the name was not allowed into his imperial position (but was allowed for him as king of the Romans).

Comment: Because they were [Germans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Roman_Empire), not [Greeks and Romans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greco-Roman_world).